# How to resolve the component must be declared using oracle Types

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two oracle types like

```
create or replace 
TYPE T_EMPLOYEE 
AS TABLE OF O_EMPLOYEE;
```

And my O_EMPLOYEE TYPE is

```
create or replace 
TYPE O_EMPLOYEE
AS OBJECT 
   (
      EMP_NAME                        VARCHAR2(50),
      EMP_ID                          VARCHAR2(50),
      EMP_DES             VARCHAR2(50)

    );
```

I am using this as an input in a store procedure where i need to check for the validation of name,id and designation. Using following i can convert the table in a select statement.

```
TABLE(CAST( I_T_EMPLOYEE AS T_EMPLOYEE)) emp,
```

but I tried to read the value like like T_EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME, it is saying componenet EMP_NAME must be decalred.

can any one help?

Comment: You should use variable to access values not the type itself. Post complete code to make your approach more clear.

Comment: What do you get if you do a query like this `SELECT * FROM <YOUR_TABLE> NATURAL JOIN TABLE(I_T_EMPLOYEE)`?

Answer (score 0):

thank you shabilan. There are two ways we can retrieve the value. first one

By writing following in store procedure. you need to declare the variables for

```
  IS 

  V_EMP_NAME                        VARCHAR2(50),
  V_EMP_ID                          VARCHAR2(50),
  V_EMP_DES                         VARCHAR2(50),

  BEGIN

  SELECT PROCESS_TYPE,REQUEST_TYPE,STATUS,EFFECTIVE_DATE_RANGE  
  INTO V_EMP_NAME, V_EMP_ID, V_EMP_DES
  FROM TABLE(CAST(I_T_EMPLOYEE AS T_EMPLOYEE)) ITE;
   --validation part
  if(V_EMP_NAME is null or V_EMP_ID or V_EMP_DES ) then RAISE NULL_DATA;
    END IF;
```

This one will fail if you pass multiple Object Types in store procedure like

```
    T_E_I :=T_EMPLOYEE(O_EMPLOYEE('Test','1234','manager'),
               O_EMPLOYEE('Test','1234','manager'));
GET_DATA_PKG.EMPLOYEE_ORDER_BY_ROLE(T_E_I,                                                                                     :o_error_code, 
                                    :o_error_message);
```

2nd approach handles the multiple inputs. this is done using cursor.you need to declare the variables for

```
  IS 

  OEM                               O_EMPLOYEE  := O_EMPLOYEE(null,null,null);
  c_EMP_NAME                        OEM.EMP_NAME%type,
  c_EMP_ID                          OEM.EMP_ID%type,
  c_EMP_DES                         OEM.EMP_DES%type,

  Cursor emp_role_curs is
  SELECT PROCESS_TYPE,REQUEST_TYPE,STATUS,EFFECTIVE_DATE_RANGE
  FROM TABLE(CAST(I_T_EMPLOYEE AS T_EMPLOYEE)) ITE;

  BEGIN
  OPEN emp_role_curs;
  loop
  fetch emp_role_curs into C_EMP_NAME, C_EMP_ID, C_EMP_DES
  FROM TABLE(CAST(I_T_EMPLOYEE AS T_EMPLOYEE)) ITE;
   --validation part
  if(V_EMP_NAME is null or V_EMP_ID or V_EMP_DES ) then RAISE NULL_DATA;
    END IF;
  EXIT WHEN emp_role_curs%notfound;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE emp_role_curs;
```

I hope this is useful if some one want to read the object type as a table.